# Getting the text label from attribute id

Tags: magento-1.8, category, product-attribute

On a category page if I use the layered navigation and filter I get a URL like /men?product_attributes=141

My question is how can I get the label of the product attribute 141

Answer (score 1):

I think I have sorted

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("product_attributes");
        if ($attr->usesSource()) {
            $color_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText("141");
        }
```